# Using inheritance to alter a superclass's interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, interface

I come from a web-development background.  I've been playing around with a bit of Java recently and have come across the following issue that seems to stem from the strict interfaces and data-typing which are more part of Java than they are of PHP.

I am using an existing physics engine ([Phys2D](http://www.cokeandcode.com/phys2d/)) to develop a game of sorts.  This  physics engine has `Body` objects managed by a `World`, and have various forces applied to them as the world is stepped.  It is important for the AI in the game that the bodies have colours (so that they can be sensed), but this is not supported by the physics engine, so I've created a subclass, and extended the `Body` class to include this - http://pastebin.com/1nLYWg3w.  Now when I create these `Body` instances, I can get them back from the `World` and get their colours.

However, Netbeans is saying that it

```
cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method getColour()
    location: class net.phys2d.raw.Body
```

because the `Body` objects returned by the physics engine interface do not contain this method.  I know that, at runtime, *all* the `Body` objects that are passed to the `World` will actually be objects of `ColouredBody` type, and so will have this method defined in their interfaces.

How can I attach colours to the `Body` objects and not produce scary underscores and warnings?  I understand that I can alter Phys2D itself but, potential licensing restrictions aside (the licence says that you *can* do this with Phys2D), I am told that this is bad practice.

Comment: I linked to pastebin to avoid cluttering up the question.  Please advise if this would be more appropriate in the post itself.  Also, if there is any way I can make the post more generic for other people, please edit or request the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'd say it would be perfectly good design to add the colour property to the Body class of the engine itself.

If you can't do that or don't want to, all you have to do is cast the `Body` instances to `ColouredBody` before using them:

```
((ColouredBody)body).getColour();
```

This tells the compiler "I know that `body` is really an instance of `ColouredBody`, so let me use it like one" - but if it turns out not to be at any time, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'm going to edit the existing class, as this seems much more elegant.  If I was not allowed to edit the library, and if there were no easier options, I would cast.

Answer (score 2):

If you know at runtime that all your `Body` objects are actually `ColouredBody`, then you can cast those objects to `ColouredBody` and call `getColour`:

```
Body body = ...;
ColouredBody colouredBody = (ColouredBody) body;
colouredBody.getColour();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to the concrete type:

```
ColouredBody cbody = (ColouredBody) body;
```

preferably, just to avoid problems, you can check whether it's really true:

```
if (body instanceof ColouredBody) {..}
```

Note that downcasting (from more general to more concrete class) is usually considered a bad practice.

If it is possible, you can try to extend `World` with `ColouredWorld` and override methods that return `Body` to return `ColouredBody` (and also hold the bodies in the proper collection), but that might be an overkill depending on the complexity.